# Lex rule for C preprocessor directive

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, lex

I am writing a lex program to tokenize a **C** program. I've written the following rule to match a **C** preprocessor directive

```
 #.*                             {printf("\n%s is a PREPROCESSOR DIRECTIVE",yytext);}
```

But when I use a file as an input to yyin, pre-processor directives in the file are matched by yytext displayed is empty

e.g I get

```
is a PREPROCESSOR DIRECTIVE
```

There is no problem when ***yyin*** is **stdin** but this arises only when a file is input. Is there an alternate LEX rule?

Comment: You usually parse an already preprocessed C program. And why do you want to tokenize a C program? Can't you use some existing C parser, or extend some existing compiler (e.g. with http://gcc-melt.org/ for example, for `gcc`)?

Comment: It's an exercise in our Compiler lab practice subject

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the fact that it doesn't work with a file instead of the lex specification, because that is more likely to cause the problem. The `printf` in the `lex` file should always at least print the `#`. The following does work with a file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%%
#.* { printf("'%s' preproc\n", yytext); }
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        if (argc > 1)
        {
                if ((yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open `%s'.\n", argv[1]);
                        exit(1);
                }
        }
        return (yylex());
}
```